# Ubuntu boots only out of installer: All boot options are tried

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi

I have Ativ 9 Lite, on which I have installed the Ubuntu (Gnome) 14.04 daily.

I after I complete the install and restart using the option offered at the end of the installation procedure, Ubuntu boots fine (from the SSD).

However, if I now restart (or start from cold) it gives the error:

> All boot options are tried.
>
> Press F4 key to recover with factory image using Recovery
>
> or any other keys for next boot loop iteration.

I have a EFI (with boot flag) and a / partition. The firmware boot order list is empty.

I have set both Secure boot and Fast boot to disabled, and the firmware looks for both UEFI and CSM.

How do I make the firmware find Ubuntu, as the installer also could?

here is my boot-repair output:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6986125/

Comment: Did you try changing the booting preference order?

Comment: actually, the boot preference order is empty, I added this to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I had a similar problem, [boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) solved it for me. If it so happens that you also have some kind of problem with MBR/partition table/etc this may help you. Simply make a bootable usb with 'startup disk creator` (details [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)), boot from usb, follow on screen instructions.

Comment: I ran the boot-repair, it said successful, but no luck. still the same message

Comment: correction, that did work when I ran repair file system: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6986180/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got it booting, but I want to point out one problem that's likely not been corrected: Your `/dev/sda2` is marked as being an [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) but it's not actually an ESP. You can correct this in `parted` or GParted by removing the "boot flag" from `/dev/sda2` or in `gdisk` by changing the type code from EF00 to 8300.

This error probably crept in because you misunderstood the nature of the "boot flag" on GPT disks. Unfortunately, the `parted` developers chose to re-use the MBR "boot flag" terminology on GPT disks, but for a concept (the ESP) that's only peripherally related to what the MBR boot flag is. Unlike the MBR boot flag, what `parted` shows as a "boot flag" on a GPT disk identifies an ESP, and should therefore be applied only to the ESP, which is a FAT32 partition that holds EFI boot loaders. Marking an ext4fs partition as an ESP is an error, which could cause problems in the future, when some future utility comes along and misbehaves because it sees two "ESPs" on the disk, one of which is non-FAT.

Comment: thanks for going through all of that, I just opened GParted and it does indeed show that. Also, sda1 is mounted at /boot/efi. If I understand you correctly I should remove the boot flag from sda2?

Comment: Correct. Leave `/dev/sda1` alone, though.